# Measure 25A Current In Series?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics

I am working on a DC battery charger project, and there is a dispute that the battery charger does not charge up to the stated 12V / 25A rating (300 watts).

We've connected the DC battery charger to an electronic DC load at a constant voltage of 12V, and it draws 20A maximum (which is below the stated limit, and sets a firestorm of regulatory issues since the product need to meet 25A as per the stated ratings).

I understand there is variation in battery voltage vs. the nominal voltage (so the current can change), but we do not see this device ever output anything close to the stated power output.

If we connect two or three nominal 12V batteries simultaneously then we can coax the charger up to 24A.

The designer thinks we have set up the measurement incorrectly and is waffling on why the watt output is so flaky.

I am thinking to illustrate the point further, we will get a 12V battery and remove the electronic DC load.  I wanted to nail down the measurement connections and terminations with the designer so there is no dispute about "the test setup" and then wire in a ammeter in series to measure the current.

I am seeing on high-end Fluke multimeters they are only able to measure 10A of current safely.

What can be used in series to safely measure up to 25A of current?  I'm seeing clamp style multi-meters, is there anything else like a more traditional meter that can be wired up in series for the measurement?

Comment: A low value resistor. Measure its voltage with a meter. I=V/R

Comment: There are 4 pin current sense resistors (2 for passing high current and the rest for measurement). A 5-milliOhm one dissipates more than 3 Watts though.

Comment: @Rohat Kılıç - interesting, I've never seen one of these.  This could work, but I'm really hoping someone has installed one of these in a system with an LCD display and characterized it so this is just a plug and play purchase of something to make this measurement.

Comment: If this charger is for lead-acid batteries, it should produce up to 14.4 volts to fully charge the battery.

Comment: @Leroy105 You already have the multimeter to measure the voltage.  All you need is the sense (or "shunt") resistor.  Actually, the 10A range on your multimeter is just measuring the voltage across an internal resistor.

Comment: Get a 100A shunt. Why not a 25A shunt? Because most common shunts are rated to drop 70mV at their rated current, which is quite high and would affect the charging. A 100A shunt will drop 70mV/4 (about 18mV) which is easily measurable with a good DMM. (Also make sure you're using really fat short cables for these experiments, not test leads!)

Comment: @Peter Bennett -- that's very interesting.  Because we are running into more of a compliance issue as to why power output with the electronic load at a constant 12V is not able to scale up to to the stated power output.  (For example, the test jig is actually some huge power resistors in lieu of the actual battery).

Comment: As @PeterBennett said, if you can only supply a voltage of 12V then your battery charger will not be able to charge a battery. There's no point in worrying about how much current your device provides if it is not able to charge a battery.

Comment: At first glance I tend to credit the designer. 25A is a lot of current and it is easy to create enough voltage drop with lab wires and plugs. The 3-battery test confirms that even more. Can you post a photo of your test setup or at least wire gauges? Also, what type of batteries you are talking about? Lead-acid? LiFePo?  NiMH? NiCD? Some exotic chemistry? The chargers usually don't out their full power always, they have some charging algorithm that changes the current with time, temperature and battery voltage and the algo pretty much depends on battery chemistry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a 4-wire current sense (shunt) resistor. This is a 0.001 ohm, probably a good choice for what you are doing.

[image]

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/murata-power-solutions-inc/3020-01096-0/811-1094-ND

Be sure to connect the high current to the top terminals and take the measurement on the side terminals. It is only calibrated if you use the side terminals for the measurement.

Comment: Even better, Murata has an integrated LCD display for use with these shunt resistors: MPS’s DCA5-20PC (check the datasheet of the resistors).

This is completely what we need.

Answer (score 1):

A Hall-effect DC clamp-on probe can perform a non-intrusive measurement. They’re a bit costly but if you do a lot of this work it will save you time, money, and argument.

And... a hacktastical solution. You can 'cheat' and use your feed wire as the sense resistor.

- Pick two points in your feed wire, one at the source and one at the end
- Force a known current through it (you already have the programmable load.)
- Measure resulting the IR drop
- Calculate R for your known I.
- Connect to your DUT load and measure the IR drop at the same points
- Divide by R, carry the one... there's your current.

This will be as accurate as any sense resistor solution, provided the wire doesn't get hot. It will be even better as it will develop many times the IR drop of a milliohm sense resistor: lead resistance will be in the tens of milliohms. Cost? Practically nothing. Invasive? Not if you have access to the wire terminals.

Even if you don't do this, and opt for a sense resistor inserted in-line, **you will still need to calibrate it by forcing a known current.** Same will be true for a clamp-on probe.

Comment: You mean like: https://www.fluke.com/en-us/product/electrical-testing/clamp-meters/fluke-325 ?

Comment: Yes, that or a current probe that can be used with a meter or a scope. I recommend the probe approach with a scope so the current waveform can be observed in real-time.

Comment: The device I mean is one that doesn't have its own display, but can be used with either a multimeter or a scope. Something like this: https://www.picotech.com/accessories/bnc-current-probes/30-a-precision-current-probe-bnc

Answer (score 1):

> I am seeing on high-end Fluke multimeters they are only able to measure 10 A of current safely.

You could use three identical 10 A meters in parallel and sum the readings.

Most of the Fluke meters have 20 A capacity for short duration. Check the manual.

Comment: It's a DC charging application over a continuous period of time...

Comment: Although the technique works for continuous period of time (+1), have you checked the minimum and maximum series resistance added by the multimeter in ampmeter mode when you gave the number of parallel multimeters? The current divider effect may overload one multimeter, blow up its fuse, and cause a chain reaction on the other multimeters.

Comment: Unlikely but possible. (My get-out clause is that if that happens then the multimeters aren't identical!)

Answer (score 1):

You can buy Hall-effect current measurement modules - they're cheap, fast to deliver, and plug-and-play provided you have an ADC or attach a Voltmeter at the analog output.
[image]

(ignore the sentence at the top, even if it might be true if the measurement is to be used by a machine)

Allegro is a classic for these applications ; the ACS758LCB-050B-PFF-T handles +/-50A with 40mV/A sensitivity. 120kHz bandwidth / 3us is a bonus in your case, but 100µOhm series resistor might actually be more than a nice touch.

If you're planning on doing this on a regular basis a "cl-Ampmeter" might be more suited to you though (next day delivery is a bliss there also), just make sure it is not transformer-based, but Hall-effect based, and wind enough of your wire through the clamp to get the sensitivity you want.

Comment: E.g. https://www.amazon.fr/electronics-salon-Panneau-support-courant-capteur/dp/B016M6IHSM/ref=asc_df_B016M6IHSM/?tag=googshopfr-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=411426802759&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=5424149158136312865&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9055242&hvtargid=pla-421097650449&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=92403079151&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=411426802759&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=5424149158136312865&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9055242&hvtargid=pla-421097650449

Comment: I've got the Fluke on the way -- for the amount of hours of setup for the measurement, it's more economical.  Thank you for the tip on winding the wire -- I haven't played around with one of these ever.  We're going to characterize the system both ways with our electronic load + clamp meter with actual battery and try to eliminate any dispute on the system.  I may order the Murata sense resistor + LCD display as well to make a third measurement.

Comment: Note that most clamp meters can't be used to measure DC. Ones that can are designed differently, and are also generally less precise, but clamp meters are not too precise in the first place so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Hearth -- that's kind of my thoughts too on the clamp meter vs. series sense resistor argument. Thanks for chiming in!  I kind of thought the clamp meter might be a little less sensitive.  We'll have the DC load to at least see how accurate the clamp is.

Comment: I revised my comment. @Leroy105 you may want to cancel your Fluke order.

Comment: @hacktastical -- it's only a couple hundred bucks.  We'll just go with it.  If we have to present clients with results, if they see a shiny Fluke attached to the result it's a much easier sell, etc.

Comment: Shiny and fancy is good sometimes ;-) "If it works, it must be a Fluke".

Answer (score 0):

Frame challenge.  It would be a rubbish battery charger if it charged batteries at 25A with any frequency.

A *proper* battery charger will charge a deeply discharged battery at a low rate, then increase the charge rate in the midrange, achieving maximum charge rate somewhere in between 20% and 80% SOC, and then feather off charge  rate as the battery nears full.

Proper multi-stage battery charging requires you to deliver an appropriate voltage at each charge stage.   **The battery will then draw what the battery wants to draw**.

If your battery charger is just murderously bashing 25A into the battery, then either a) your charger is very, very stupid and will destroy batteries, or b) your charger is very, very smart, has an enhanceed relationship with the battery (e.g. Thermal monitoring), *and* the battery is quite large for the charger.  An eexample is Tesla, which really can Tyson-punch 50kw into a battery that small, because the battery system is designed soup to nuts to do that, with impeccable monitoring and cooling.

For instance, I have a (25A, in fact) charger that charges a 1200 pound battery.  (That's 550kg, not 1200 quid).  It's a starting battery, so it spends most of its regime above 90% SOC. The battery charger operates between 6 and 12 amps at those SOCs, and I consider that normal and I do not consider myself "ripped off".

Whoever is expecting to attach it to J random battery at J random state of charge, and immediately see 25A charge rate, is an idiot who should be drummed out of the battery business.

--

Now if you are driving into a static DC load, e.g. A resistor bank, not only cant battery chargers do that, but neither can *any* DC power supply.  If you put a 0.6 ohm (1.66666 siemens) load onto a 12V power supply, the right amount of current  to expect is 20 amps.  If you want 25 amps, you need a lower resistance (higher conductance) load.